# Linq 2 tables join but need data from 3 not needing to join all 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 tables I need to get data from well actually only 2 that I need to do a join with which  I know using `Linq` but I need the name of a project from the projected and I need to insert it into the same model Im creating using linq. I tried from proj in context.Projects where `proj.ProjectId = detail.ProjectId` but it says cant convert int to bool and I don’t have bool declared anywhere? Here is my `linq`. And the whole method actually

PS - this is my most updated action I created but still isnt 100% correct yet is this having the right idea to get 3 tables data?

```
     public ActionResult DisplayAllTimeSheetDetails(int masterid)
        {
            var masterModel = context.TimeSheetMaster.Where(w => 
                              w.TimeSheetMasterId.Equals(masterid)).FirstOrDefault();

            var detailM = context.TimeSheetDetails.Where(t => 
                          t.TimeSheetMasterId.Equals(masterModel.TimeSheetMasterId))
                          .FirstOrDefault();

            var project = context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(
                          detailM.ProjectId)).FirstOrDefault();


            var details = (from master in context.TimeSheetMaster
                           join detail in context.TimeSheetDetails
                           on master.TimeSheetMasterId equals detail.TimeSheetMasterId
                           //from proj in context.Projects where proj.ProjectId = detail.ProjectId
                           select new TimeSheetDetailsModel()
                           {
                               Sunday = detail.Sunday,
                               Monday = detail.Monday,
                               Tuesday = detail.Tuesday,
                               Wednesday = detail.Wednesday,
                               Thursday = detail.Thursday,
                               Friday = detail.Friday,
                               Saturday = detail.Saturday,
                               Hours = detail.Hours,
                               Comment = master.Comment,
                               ProjectName = project.ProjectName
                           }).ToList();

            return View(details);
        }
public class TimeSheetDetailsModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Time Sheet ID")]
        public int TimeSheetId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Day of Week")]
        public string DaysOfWeek { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Hours")]
        public int? Hours { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Period")]
        public string Period { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Project ID")]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User ID")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Time Sheet Master ID")]
        public int TimeSheetMasterId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public int Sunday { get; set; }
        public int Monday { get; set; }
        public int Tuesday { get; set; }
        public int Wednesday { get; set; }
        public int Thursday { get; set; }
        public int Friday { get; set; }
        public int Saturday { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think perhaps you might have trouble formulating your idea- I can’t follow at all

Comment: please put here models

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly join anyway? Your TimeSheetMasterDetail should have TimeSheetMaster navigational property, which you can use – EF will handle the joining implicitly. The same with your projects, where TimeSheetDetails should have a Project navigational property.

Comment: If you do need data from the 3rd table, you do need a second join (or do a separate query, but this would also just do a FK=PK index scan). However, note that LINQ syntax is c# syntax, therefore you'll need to do the PK=FK comparison with the == operator (and not the = operator in your where clause)

Comment: here is my model I am populating I have all the data in the timesheet tables EXCEPT project I need to call the 3rd table to get the project name by the Id but I do not need to do any join on it for this query I just need the projectname and here is my model im populatingn 
public int TimeSheetId { get; set; }
        public string DaysOfWeek { get; set; }
        public int? Hours { get; set; }
        public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; } + some more property fields its just a model with 3 tables fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like this. I am open to other answers and a cleaner way of doing this.

```
public ActionResult DisplayAllTimeSheetDetails(int masterid)
            {
            var masterModel = context.TimeSheetMaster.Where(w => 
                              w.TimeSheetMasterId.Equals(masterid)).FirstOrDefault();

            var detailM = context.TimeSheetDetails.Where(t =>
                          t.TimeSheetMasterId.Equals(masterModel.TimeSheetMasterId)).FirstOrDefault();//.ToList();

            var project = context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId==detailM.ProjectId).FirstOrDefault();


            var details = (from master in context.TimeSheetMaster
                           join detail in context.TimeSheetDetails
                           on master.TimeSheetMasterId equals detail.TimeSheetMasterId
                           select new TimeSheetDetailsModel()
                           {
                               Sunday = detail.Sunday,
                               Monday = detail.Monday,
                               Tuesday = detail.Tuesday,
                               Wednesday = detail.Wednesday,
                               Thursday = detail.Thursday,
                               Friday = detail.Friday,
                               Saturday = detail.Saturday,
                               Hours = detail.Hours,
                               Comment = master.Comment,
                               ProjectName = project.ProjectName
                           }).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(details);
        }
```